# PhpStorm 2017.1.3 Passive Mode

Tags: phpstorm, sftp, passive-mode

I'm using PhpStorm to edit files on a live server. When I try to upload the file it tells me "could not close the output stream for file". Note that I'm using "SFTP" ..

Some suggesting that using "passive mode" will solve the issue, but I can't find the settings when I go to: (Tools=>Deployment=>Configuration=>Advanced settings) as suggested!!

Is it even possible to use passive mode with SFTP!?

Comment: Passive/active mode is FTP(S) thing. There's nothing like that in SFTP. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/5881589/850848

Comment: There is no such thing as "Passive Mode" in SFTP. And no, passive mode doesn't help in your case. The passive mode is a feature of the FTP protocol that makes the connection possible when the client is behind a firewall (as it almost always happens nowadays). Don't switch to FTP (assuming it works for you) just to use the Passive Mode. SFTP is a modern, safe protocol (it is file transfer through SSH). FTP, with or without "S" is an old protocol that is deprecated since two decades ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passive Mode isn't available for `SFTP`. This option is only available for `FTP` and `FTPS`.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/advanced-options-dialog.html

**advanced options in comparison**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It could be a PhpStorm/jsch issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17685.
Please reproduce the issue, open Help > Show Log in ... > idea.log and look for errors. If you'll see the same messages as in aforementioned WI-17685 then you got it.